# What are some good kayak fishing areas in Friendship, Maine?

Tags: fishing, united-states

I am going to Friendship, Maine, USA, 04547, for the first week of August 2014. I am thinking about kayak fishing. Are they any good spots? What kind of fish species should I expect to find there?

Comment: The town is seaside, so I assume you are looking to go salt-water fishing.

Comment: Hi and welcome at Outdoors.SE. The question is very specific but I think it is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes it's Salt-water fishing

Comment: @Wills I was thinking the opposite in regards to the "any good spots" portion of the question. This seems to be inviting open ended lists.

Answer (score 7):

The list of fish in that area is relatively easy to find, but the trick is identifying useful areas - the fishing trip websites don't give too much away.

One useful place a friend told me about is between about 5 and 10 miles south of Friendship, northwest of Allen Island. This time of year you can expect cod, pollock and halibut. Going further south you get into trawling area, so that's maybe a bit far out for kayaking.

There is supposed to be good fishing all around the Penobscot Bay area, so have a look at http://penbay.org/wrich/fgotgom01.html for some of the fishing areas.